# How to drop columns with no data in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS Access I'm trying alter a table and remove unused columns. There are 338 columns in this particular table and many of them are completely unused I would prefer not to do this manually one by one.

What is the alter table command to drop columns that do not have any data in them? I don't know how to dynaically select the columns without data for the alter table command. Is this even possible?

Something like?

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName
DROP *columnsThatHaveNoData*
```

Comment: You'd have to use VBA.  Pull the list of columns from an empty result set from `SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE 1 = 0`.  Then for each column in the table, see if `SELECT 1 FROM MyTableName WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL` returns any rows.  if it doesn't, you know it's empty and you can issue `ALTER TABLE MyTableName DROP ColumnName`.

Comment: How can there be 338 columns? Access table is limited to 255 fields.

Comment: It's a table from another database (progress DB).